# MySQL - Value of 1 in DECIMAL(2, 2) is coming out as 0.99

Tags: mysql

I am storing monetary values, and I read that FLOAT has internal rounding problems (although I can't say I ever noticed any problems) and that it is better to use DECIMAL.

So I have been using DECIMAL but when I try to set the value to 1 it is stored as 0.99.  I will be using that value in JavaScript at some point, and I know that my JS calculations will be wrong because it is 0.99 not 1.00.

Why is it doing that and should I just use FLOAT?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need `DECIMAL(4, 2)` by the looks of things. `DECIMAL(2, 2)` only allows a range of `-0.99 to 0.99`

[The precision represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the scale represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html) so in your case you have not defined the column to allow any integer part at all.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I forgot to increase the size after I changed the type of numbers I was storing.  Sometimes you need another set of eyes!

Comment: Out of interest, what range on the negative side would DECIMAL(9, 2) give me?

Comment: Thanks.  Wasn't sure if the `-` counts as part of the characters.